# django 1.10 Exception while resolving variable 'is_popup' in template 'admin/login.html'

Tags: python, django

I create a new django project with python3.5 and django1.10.0,I keep getting an error in the admin whenever I want access `localhost:8000/admin`, He`re's the error:

```
[DEBUG]- Exception while resolving variable 'is_popup' in template 'admin/login.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 885, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 75, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'is_popup'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 891, in _resolve_lookup
    if isinstance(current, BaseContext) and getattr(type(current), bit):
AttributeError: type object 'RequestContext' has no attribute 'is_popup'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 900, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'is_popup'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 907, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [is_popup] in "[{'True': True, 'None': None, 'False': False}, {'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x04A2D1D0>, 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'WARNING': 30, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'ERROR': 40, 'INFO': 20, 'DEBUG': 10}, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x04A0A590>>, 'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x04A0A490>, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/admin/login/?next=/admin/'>, 'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: <function csrf.<locals>._get_val at 0x04581C90>>}, {}, {'has_permission': False, 'username': '', 'site_title': <django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__ object at 0x03CF82B0>, 'next': '/admin/', 'site': <django.contrib.sites.requests.RequestSite object at 0x04A0A6D0>, 'app_path': '/admin/login/?next=/admin/', 'site_url': '/', 'site_name': '127.0.0.1:8000', 'available_apps': [], 'LANGUAGE_BIDI': False, 'LANGUAGE_CODE': 'en-us', 'form': <AdminAuthenticationForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(username;password)>, 'site_header': <django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__ object at 0x03CF8310>, 'title': 'Log in'}]"
2016-10-16 09:31:59,199 [Thread-7:11460] [django.template:929] [base:_resolve_lookup] [DEBUG]- Exception while resolving variable 'is_popup' in template 'admin/login.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 885, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 75, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'is_popup'
```

Anyone can help me,thanks very much!

Comment: Show us the `admin/login.html` template.

Comment: I do not create any html file,the admin/login.html is in django framework in `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html`  @JohnGordon

Comment: Exception while resolving variable 'is_popup' in template `admin/index.html` the same exception

Comment: resolve the issue because the logging level is debug. `'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),

            'propagate': True,
        },
    },` set the logging level to info then it works!!!

Comment: I should point out that changing the logging level doesn't fix errors, but just doesn't log the errors.

Comment: Same here on Django 1.10 and 1.11

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42744418/6719157

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error with is\_popup variable in django 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797884/getting-error-with-is-popup-variable-in-django-1-9)

Answer (score 3):

I came across this error, and it turned out to be because I had put `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True` in my main settings file and forgotten to put `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False` in my dev settings (as with the OP this was while using `manage.py runserver`, so secure cookies were not possible).

Comment: You made my day. I had spent 2 hour to resolve this issue and your comment made my day. Thank you.