# Django failed to lookup for key 'is_popup'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here is my errorlog, I am using django 2.1.3, python 3.6 with pipenv

> django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key
>   [is_popup] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None},
>   {'csrf_token': ._get_val at
>   0x7f99c8459400>>, 'request': , 'user': >,
>   'perms': , 'messages':
>   , 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'INFO': 20,
>   'SUCCESS': 25, 'WARNING': 30, 'ERROR': 40}}, {}, {'form':
>   , 'view':
>   ,
>   'site_title': 'XXD', 'site_header': 'XXD', 'site_url': '/',
>   'has_permission': False, 'available_apps': [], 'title': 'Log in',
>   'app_path': '/admin/login/?next=/admin/', 'username': '', 'next':
>   '/admin/', 'site': , 'site_name': 'localhost:8081', 'LANGUAGE_CODE':
>   'en-us', 'LANGUAGE_BIDI': False}]
>
> INFO 2018-11-24 17:45:28,796 basehttp 5201 140298476877568 "GET
>   /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1828 ('GET
>   /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1', '200', '1828') null

I am receiving this on open of django admin panel. Because of this it is not redirecting to next page even after successfully login.

Comment: Here is the Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066019/django-1-10-exception-while-resolving-variable-is-popup-in-template-admin-log