# Django LDAP authn backend: user authenticated but unable to login

Tags: django, ldap

I have a strange issue with django ldap backend.

this is my configuration:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://XXXXXXx"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "CN=Pti Release,OU=Service-Accounts,OU=DD,DC=ad,DC=como,DC=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "XXXXXXXX"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("OU=DD,DC=ad,DC=como,DC=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)")
AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT: False,
}

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("OU=DD,DC=ad,DC=como,DC=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)")

AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
  "is_superuser" : "CN=airflow-super-users_GLOBAL,OU=Global,OU=Security-Groups,OU=DD,DC=ad,DC=como,DC=com",
     "is_active" : "CN=airflow-data-profilers_GLOBAL,OU=Global,OU=Security-Groups,OU=DD,DC=ad,DC=como,DC=com",
}

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType()

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'main.UserProfile'

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
    "country": "c"
}
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True

AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600
```

When I attempt to login, the django auth_user is populated correctly but django shows me this form:

Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

And no way to login.

Any ideas?

I'm adding here more information which can help to debug this. I know yo will notice `VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [is_popup]` but it seems not be an error [Getting error with is_popup variable in django 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797884/getting-error-with-is-popup-variable-in-django-1-9). I'm using these packages have been installed into the django virtualenv:

- appdirs==1.4.3
- coreapi==2.3.0
- coreschema==0.0.4
- Django==1.11
- django-auth-ldap==1.2.11
- django-crispy-forms==1.6.1
- django-enumchoicefield==0.8.0
- django-enumfields==0.9.0
- django-filter==1.0.2
- django-filters==0.2.1
- django-mysql==1.1.1
- djangorestframework==3.6.2
- drf-enum-field==0.9.1
- enum==0.4.6
- enum34==1.1.6
- itypes==1.1.0
- Jinja2==2.9.6
- MarkupSafe==1.0
- MySQL-python==1.2.5
- packaging==16.8
- pyparsing==2.2.0
- python-ldap==2.4.38
- pytz==2017.2
- requests==2.13.0
- six==1.10.0
- uritemplate==3.0.0

Database before the login attempt

mysql> select *  from auth_user\G

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
          id: 1
    password: pbkdf2_sha256$36000$giZoAk1hhuFG$aSJ1w6nOs05VjecVnFVFVYTK2h84mqHqDTKg5St6BBE=
  last_login: 2017-05-04 08:28:05.580156
is_superuser: 1
    username: root
  first_name: 
   last_name: 
       email: 
    is_staff: 1
   is_active: 1
 date_joined: 2017-04-10 13:27:46.202097
```

django logs ( DEBUG=True, output to console )

```
DEBUG search_s('OU=DD,DC=ad,DC=como,DC=com', 2, '(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)') returned 1 objects: cn=alessio palma,ou=hr,ou=florence,ou=italy,ou=dd,dc=ad,dc=como,dc=com
DEBUG (0.000) SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
DEBUG (0.000) SELECT VERSION(); args=None
DEBUG (0.002) SELECT `auth_user`.`id`, `auth_user`.`password`, `auth_user`....
DEBUG (0.001) INSERT INTO `auth_user` (`password`, `last_login`, `is_superuser`... 
DEBUG (0.001) INSERT INTO `authtoken_token` (`key`, `user_id`, `created`) VALUES ('91567e9aece75cd7fc97809b8685267fc53bc983', 7, '2017-05-05 06:21:15.359687'); args=(u'91567e9aece75cd7fc97809b8685267fc53bc983', 7, u'2017-05-05 06:21:15.359687')
DEBUG Created Django user alessio.palma
DEBUG Populating Django user alessio.palma
DEBUG cn=alessio palma,ou=hr,ou=florence,ou=italy,ou=dd,dc=ad,dc=como,dc=com is a member of cn=airflow-super-users_global,ou=global,ou=security-groups,ou=dd,dc=ad,dc=como,dc=com
DEBUG cn=alessio palma,ou=hr,ou=florence,ou=italy,ou=dd,dc=ad,dc=como,dc=com is a member of cn=airflow-data-profilers_global,ou=global,ou=security-groups,ou=dd,dc=ad,dc=como,dc=com
DEBUG (0.001) UPDATE `auth_user` SET `password` = '!QBPYrozr5C3wMRneLcBJeiWmaE4YiTizNgJURGTQ', `last_login` = NULL, `is_superuser` = 1, `username` = 'alessio.palma', `first_name` = 'Alessio', `last_name` = 'Palma', `email` = 'xxxxx@como.com', `is_staff` = 0, `is_active` = 1, `date_joined` = '2017-05-05 06:21:15.357377' WHERE `auth_user`.`id` = 7; args=(u'!QBPYrozr5C3wMRneLcBJeiWmaE4YiTizNgJURGTQ', True, u'alessio.palma', u'Alessio', u'Palma', u'alessio.palma@docomodigital.com', False, True, u'2017-05-05 06:21:15.357377', 7)
DEBUG Exception while resolving variable 'is_popup' in template 'admin/login.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/room/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [is_popup] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {u'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: <function _get_val at 0x7f5af0051d70>>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f5af83a7cd0>>, 'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x7f5af005e690>, 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'INFO': 20, 'WARNING': 30, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'ERROR': 40}, 'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x7f5af8484c10>, u'request': <WSGIRequest: POST '/admin/login/?next=/admin/'>}, {}, {'username': u'', 'app_path': u'/admin/login/?next=/admin/', 'available_apps': [], 'site_name': '172.17.0.2:8000', 'form': <AdminAuthenticationForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(username;password)>, 'title': u'Log in', 'site_header': u'Django administration', 'site': <django.contrib.sites.requests.RequestSite object at 0x7f5af84b6d50>, 'next': u'/admin/', 'site_title': u'Django site admin', u'LANGUAGE_CODE': 'en-us', 'has_permission': False, 'site_url': '/', u'LANGUAGE_BIDI': False, u'view': <django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView object at 0x7f5af83a7e10>}]"
DEBUG Exception while resolving variable 'is_popup' in template 'admin/login.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/room/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [is_popup] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {u'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: <function _get_val at 0x7f5af0051d70>>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f5af83a7cd0>>, 'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x7f5af005e690>, 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'INFO': 20, 'WARNING': 30, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'ERROR': 40}, 'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x7f5af8484c10>, u'request': <WSGIRequest: POST '/admin/login/?next=/admin/'>}, {}, {'username': u'', 'app_path': u'/admin/login/?next=/admin/', 'available_apps': [], 'site_name': '172.17.0.2:8000', 'form': <AdminAuthenticationForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(username;password)>, 'title': u'Log in', 'site_header': u'Django administration', 'site': <django.contrib.sites.requests.RequestSite object at 0x7f5af84b6d50>, 'next': u'/admin/', 'site_title': u'Django site admin', u'LANGUAGE_CODE': 'en-us', 'has_permission': False, 'site_url': '/', u'LANGUAGE_BIDI': False, u'view': <django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView object at 0x7f5af83a7e10>}]"
INFO "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1819
```

Database after the login attempt

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
          id: 1
    password: pbkdf2_sha256$36000$giZoAk1hhuFG$aSJ1w6nOs05VjecVnFVFVYTK2h84mqHqDTKg5St6BBE=
  last_login: 2017-05-04 08:28:05.580156
is_superuser: 1
    username: root
  first_name: 
   last_name: 
       email: 
    is_staff: 1
   is_active: 1
 date_joined: 2017-04-10 13:27:46.202097
*************************** 2. row ***************************
          id: 7
    password: !QBPYrozr5C3wMRneLcBJhiWmaE4YiTizNgJURGTQ
  last_login: NULL
is_superuser: 1
    username: alessio.palma
  first_name: Alessio
   last_name: Palma
       email: xxxxxx@como.com
    is_staff: 0
   is_active: 1
 date_joined: 2017-05-05 06:21:15.357377
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

HELP! I think all this problem is the usual comma out of place.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

When you set the ldap authentication, users are loaded into the django's auth_user table and is_staff is set to 0.  So you can't login also if you are a valid ldap user.

Next step is to login as admin or update the auth_user table setting is_staff to 1 to every user which has to login.
After this update, you can access django using you ldap account.

Answer (score 0):

AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH simply didn't find a matching user.  If it's Active Directory you should be able to use [Direct Bind](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/authentication.html#direct-bind) to get rid of the explicit user search.  Otherwise you could [enable logging](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/logging.html) to gain more insight.

Comment: The user is loaded from ldap and inserted into the the django tables, also logs show that the record on ldap has been found. There is something which does not allow django to login the user.

Comment: If the user exists in the directory and you still can't bind successfully, it may be disabled.  Again, logging might me helpful.